# Pod Install Fails for EAS Build - React Native Expo

Tags: node.js, ruby, react-native, cocoapods, node-modules

I am attempting to deploy my ios internal distribution build for a project.

When I run:

`eas build --profile development --platform ios`

The result is:

```
Using Expo Modules
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ExpoModulesCore
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ReactCommon
Auto-generating `.xcode.env.local` with $NODE_BINARY=/Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin/node
error Failed to build the app: No package name found. Found errors in /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-av/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 783: unexpected token at 'info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
'.
 #  from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Podfile:14
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    use_expo_modules!
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #  
 #  ———————————————————————--------------------
```

It appears that the pod install fails. I attached a screenshot below. This is my first time running this on a brand new M3 Macbook Pro.

[image: pod install fails]

I tried yarn install and reinstalling cocoa pods and have been getting the same error.

Comment: I suspect the error comes from the fact that there is `no package name`. If you. have access to `Xcode`, i would advise to make a `package name`. If not, you can always create it in the `app.json / app.config.json`

Answer (score 0):

`expo upgrade` fixed this for me